# customize the style of rc-time-picker

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, timepicker

I am using `rc-time-picker` package for my project, but I have problem with customizing the style of `pop-up` of my `time picker` component. Here is the screenshot of my component:

[image: screenshot of component]

Firstly, I need to change the background-color of time `item` in the time `li` from `light grey` (in the screenshot) to `#edeffe` when time is hovered and selected . The following is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import TimePicker from "rc-time-picker";
import "rc-time-picker/assets/index.css";
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledTimePicker = styled(TimePicker)`
 &.rc-time-picker-panel-select-option-selected{
    background-color: #edeffe !important;
  }
`;

const DeliTimePicker = ({ value, onChange, ...others }) => {
  return (
    <StyledTimePicker
      showSecond={false}
      onChange={onChange}
      hideDisabledOptions
      minuteStep={5}
      {...others}
      value={value}
      use12Hours
    />
  );
};

export default DeliTimePicker;
```

From the inspection in the browser, I find the `className` of each item when selected is `rc-time-picker-panel-select-option-selected`. I also have to use `styled component` package for styling in my project. I can't figure out why it doesn't work via this method. The final component should look like this:

[image: final rendering]

This is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/kk8lllwwp7?fontsize=14

Any answer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The &. is not needed.

Comment: It still doesn't work if I remove them.

Comment: TRy adding this 
 &:hover {
    background: #hexcode;
  }

Comment: They still can't work. From inspection in the browser, this css code even doesn't appear under the `className` from both method.

Comment: hmm, can you create a code sandbox and I'll take a look

Comment: This is the link I just created: https://codesandbox.io/s/kk8lllwwp7?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rearrange the order in which you're stylizing your `TimePicker` component. The `styled-components` package generates a `className` that needs to be applied to the `TimePicker`. In this case, it'll be applied to both its `className` and its `popupClassName`

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Styled Time Picker]

**components/TimePicker/index.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import TimePicker from "./TimePicker";

const StyledTimePicker = styled(TimePicker)`
  & .rc-time-picker-panel-select-option-selected {
    background-color: #edeffe;
    font-weight: normal;
  }

  & .rc-time-picker-clear,
  & .rc-time-picker-clear-icon:after {
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  & .rc-time-picker-panel-select,
  & .rc-time-picker-input,
  & .rc-time-picker-panel-input {
    font-family: "Consolas", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
    }
  }
`;

export default StyledTimePicker;
```

**components/TimePicker/TimePicker.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import moment from "moment";
import TimePicker from "rc-time-picker";
import "rc-time-picker/assets/index.css";

const DeliTimePicker = ({ className, onChange, value, ...rest }) => (
  <TimePicker
    {...rest}
    className={className}
    popupClassName={className}
    showSecond={false}
    onChange={onChange}
    hideDisabledOptions
    minuteStep={5}
    value={value}
    use12Hours
  />
);

DeliTimePicker.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.instanceOf(moment)
};

export default DeliTimePicker;
```

**components/TimeSelectForm/index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import TimePicker from "../TimePicker";

class TimeSelectForm extends Component {
  state = {
    value: moment()
  };

  handleChange = value => this.setState({ value });

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(moment(this.state.value).format("hh:mm a"));
  };

  render = () => (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <TimePicker value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default TimeSelectForm;
```