# How to add text outline effect to ant-design Icon using styled-components (example in Sandbox)?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, styled-components

I'm looking to add text outline effect to my ant design Icon.

My current code is the following:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Icon } from 'antd';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const MyIcon = styled(Icon)`
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: lightgrey;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
`;


const App = () => (
  <MyIcon type="arrows-alt"/>
);

render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

The `lightgrey` color is applied but somehow I can't get it to add the `text-stroke` feature.

I've got this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8l352p6w12) illustrating the problem.

[image]

Comment: Same way as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189678/customize-the-style-of-rc-time-picker/55192001#55192001 (just change the className selections to the classes generated by ant)

Comment: you will not be able to do the stroke and shadows to antd's icons, Type using custom svg icons https://ant.design/components/icon/#components-icon-demo-custom

Comment: I gave up on antd... I ended up creating my own icons. Thanks!